# PLESK: How to transfer Plesk (Obsidian) firewall-settings from old to new system

Tags: firewall, plesk

Plesk (according their documentation) does not support the transfer of serverwide settings as part of their migration module.

As the Plesk (as far as I understand it) maintains their own database of firewall settings, from which an iptables-procedre is generated, the following transfer procedures also fail:

- `iptables-save / iptables-restore`
- copy of the iptables generating file `firewall-active.sh`

Simply as they are all overwritten by the next generation process.

So my question:

Has anyone a practical solution (proposal) how to efficiently transfer the firewall-settings from an old to a new system

Environment: Debian 9 to 11
Plesk: Obsidian 18 (both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a direct transfer is not provided by Plesk, I have found the following workaround.

There is a CLI tool `/usr/local/psa/bin/modules/firewall/settings` which enables you  to create and update firewall rules and activate/de-activate the Plesk firewall. It allows to specify a list of IP's and CIDR's to be written to the Plesk database.

With `/usr/local/psa/bin/modules/firewall/settings --help` you get an overview what you can do with this tool. Just be cautious as the description is not 100% correct. Eg. the command options  are not comma-separated nor positional, and the `-p` short option is not correct for the remote-addresses.

The inserts and updates are all made to the Plesk database and are therefore "persistent" (as opposed to changes directly made to iptables).

The `-id`-parameter for updates for a certain rule can be located as part of the URL referencing the rule in Plesk (self explanatory).

I personally have not activated and confirmed my updates via this tool, instead I have verified my settings within Plesk and then activated and confirmed it there.